# A New Proof of Pythagorean theorem?

Tags: geometry, proof-writing, solution-verification

A right triangle with side lengths $a,b,c$  where the hypotenuse($c$) intercepts the height($h$) such that $c$ is the sum of $2$ side lengths, $c = m + n$.

Image here: [image]

I found an elegant proof of Pythagorean theorem that seems to be related to Einstein's proof:

First, slopes of $a$ and $b$ give:

$$(\frac{h}{m})(\frac{h}{n}) = 1\implies h^2 = mn$$

Than with area formula, we find the intercept $(x,y)$ of the height and hypotenuse:

$$bx = hm\implies x = \frac{am}{c}$$
$$ay = hn\implies y = \frac{bn}{c}$$

Next plugging this into the height's equation:

$$\frac{a}{b}(\frac{am}{c}) = 
\frac{bn}{c}\implies a^2m = b^2n$$

Using $c = m  + n$:

$$\frac{c}{\sqrt{mn}} = \sqrt{\frac{m}{n}} + \sqrt{\frac{n}{m}}$$
$$\frac{c^2}{ab} = \frac{a}{b} + \frac{b}{a}$$
$$a^2 + b^2 = c^2$$

*Q.E.D.*

Thoughts?

Comment: not sure what you would like to see? seems like a valid proof, not particularly short though. Are you asking for other more elegant ones? Or for validity check of your argument?

Comment: Checking the argument

Comment: The height here is actually a perpendicular bisector on $AB$, right?

Comment: @CameronWilliams by definition, i think

Comment: Instead of "elegant" maybe "straightforward algebraic" proof (for me, those are the kinds I find elegant).

Comment: So this is what we're working with? https://i.imgur.com/jA8Z4g5.png

Comment: It's a mix of appeals to plane geometry and Cartesian coordinates.  As such it's hard to be sure that circular reasoning has been avoided.  It would be good to supply more details for the justification of steps.  For example, you wrote $bx = hm \implies x = \frac{am}{c}$ with no explanation of how $b,h$ disappear and $a,c$ appear.

Comment: @hardmath I was taking the assumption that h = ab/c, by definition of its name

Comment: I like area-based proofs of Pythagoras' theorem https://newtonexcelbach.com/tag/wordless-proof/ ;)

Comment: @Cameron Williams excactly, :)

Comment: @SpoonedBread Okay great. I'm going to add it to your post.

Comment: @PM 2Ring A diagram has now been provided , so it should be more understandable

Comment: Even though the proof turned out to be a more complicated version of a known proof, kudos to you for having independently discovered it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is really just an overly complex use of similar triangles to show$$m/a=h/b,\,n/b=h/a\implies c=m+n=(a^2+b^2)/c,$$where in the last $=$ I, like you, have used $ab=ch$. As with your other questions I've answered about Pythagorean proofs, the strategy works but is intimately related, once extraneous Cartesian coordinates have been stripped away, to old approaches. In particular, computing $x,\,y$ is equivalent to computing $m,\,n$, so there's no need to worry about how axes are oriented.

Answer (score 2):

Two little right triangles and the original one are similar. Then proof follows after simply two to three lines arithmetic.